# use case diagrams include and extend

Tags: user-interface, include, uml, extend, use-case

I've  a simple scenario that shows mouse and keyboard interactions with GUI.
Mouse And keyboard can select UI elements and then click on them or press Enter/Space to trigger their action.
which one of these diagrams shows the correct form of my scenario in use case diagram?
and by the way I don't know if they are correct UML diagrams :)
Or do you think there are many details involved in these use cases?

**First Use Case :** 
[image]

**Second Use Case :** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way too fine-grained for setting up a use-case diagram. :)
Have you tried other diagram types to better match this level of detail?